# What are better alternatives to getters and setters in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, accessor

I have read some about the use of getters/setters in object oriented programming and many resources such as [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html?page=1) suggest that they should be used very infrequently.  A quote from that article says:

> Don't ask for the information you need to do the work; ask the object that has the information to do the work for you.

While that sounds good in principle, I'm not particularly sure how that is best implemented.  Say taht I have a class the describes a car.  Inside that class, lets say that the brand of this car stored in the class is "Toyota".  Now I have a GUI that wants to display that this is a "Toyota".  How does one do that without a getter?

Even if I abstract out that the "Toyota" is stored as a String and return a TextBox with "Toyota" already written in it, this sounds, at best, like a getter of a wrapped form of the original property.  I just thought that things like TextBoxes should be only in the GUI's class, and not in helper classes like my car class here.

Comment: This is philosophy, you can take it too far. I've never seen an article exhorting such purism of OO design, that also includes an example with code showing how you would actually *do* something practical like represent a car. That said, the philosophy is worth understanding, but if you replace a property with two methods that read and write an inner field, what have you accomplished?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering through that whole article when they would have code examples, but alas, they did not.  Other articles of a similar nature had some examples for replacing setters, but not getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring "to do the work". If the work you want done is the brand of the car, then a getter that returns the brand does the work.

What the article is saying is if you want work done on class data, put the work in the class. Do not pull data out of the class, do work on it, then return it to the class:

```
var c = new Car();
c.Odometer += 10;  // bad
c.DriveMiles(10);  // good
```

I also question how applicable that article is to C#; it claims:

> Getter and setter methods (also known as accessors) are dangerous for the same reason that public fields are dangerous: They provide external access to implementation details.

In C# this is false, a C# accessor can accept arbitrary classes, they do not "provide external access to implementation details".

Comment: So if I understand you correctly it is okay to use the getter if that is waht I want, but not so that I can get it, and do work with it other than displaying or something of the like?  So if I had another field about the model, I wouldn't have  String brandmodel = car.getBrand() + car.getModel(), I would just have something in my car class that does that for me like car.getBrandModel() ?

Comment: Holub's original article would probably say you have `car.describeMyself`. The problem is that you replace one problem with another. Now your car has to have some knowledge of the context of describing itself: for what purpose is this description needed? An ad? Paying tolls? Taxes? Something you didn't think of? Now you've got a whole new abstraction needed, that will (in the end) just be duplicative of exposing properties of a car. I think methods should do something inherent to the object (which is why I like this answer) but an object shouldn't have or need knowledge of how it's used.

Comment: The vast majority of properties are just wrappers for fields--which is technically just providing external access to implementation details...

Comment: Not really, he's saying as soon as you define int SomeProperty {get; set;} the imlementation detail you've exposed  is that SomeProperty is (probably) stored as an int. Seems to be more of an arguent against adding unnecessary accessors in statically typed languages.

Comment: Note also that C# can have an accessor `BrandModel` that returns `car.Brand + car.Model` without exposing either `Brand` or `Model`, can forbid the caller from changing them, and which can be changed without changing the interface.

Comment: @DourHighArch I never understood the value of that versus just exposing `Brand` and `Model` (for read access only). Providing `BrandModel` assumes a certain need which is non-general in use. What if you had to separate them with a comma? What if you wanted the order reversed? This is a car user concern, not a car concern. Definitely provide action-specific methods to alter properties as often as possible, but concealing properties from read access in favor of a wide array of context-specific methods doesn't make sense to me. `BrandModel` should be a prop of a `CarReport` object (or nothing).

Answer (score 5):

That article is describing that you should use methods instead of property getters/setters.  Basically it's suggesting a method should perform an action to modify state instead of allowing a setter to modify state.  e.g. I could have a class with a Month and a Day property.  I could then have code that does this:

```
obj.Day = 28;
obj.Month = Months.February;
obj.Day = 30;
obj.Month = Months.March;
```

As soon as I set a day to 30 while month is February, I have invalid state.

The article suggest that a class shouldn't allow this type of thing but provide specific methods to perform specific actions, like:

```
obj.ChangeDate(Months.March, 30);
```

If a date time analogy is confusing due to DateTime, you could have a similar example with lat/long coords:

```
obj.Latitude = 45.4112;
obj.Longitude = -75.6981;
//... 
obj.Latitude = 39.73;
obj.Longitude = -86.27;
```

When Latitude is set to 39.73 the location becomes a place near Newark instead of Ottawa (the first lat/long) or Indianapolis (the second lat/long).  Leaving settings for lat/long leaves the interface open to not being able to verify its invariants and some may say not truly object-oriented.  So, you might have a method instead:

```
obj.MoveTo(39.73, -86.27);
```

OO implies both encapsulated state and behaviour.  While some may thing that properties "encapsulate" state, they normally don't.  They decouple implementation from the interface so that what is used as a backing store for the properties can change--but, it rarely ever does; so the properties are simply making available implementation details differently than providing public fields.

There are concepts like Command Query separation that build on this idea that suggest an interface should either update state or query state, but not both.  Properties with both getters and setters provide an interface that both update state and query state.  The above examples `MoveTo` and `ChangeDate` would be "commands".  Conceptually you would provide other ways of querying state; if that's needed.

One of the other problems with properties is that people habitually add both getters and setters simply because it is a property.  The ability to get or set a property may not be necessary and simply adding both a getter and a setter by rote creates and interface that requires testing and maintenance that may not ever be needed.

Subtle?  Sure; but he's talking about the object-oriented design, not code that "just works".

Comment: You could also just have a `DateTime` property, that being an object that encsapsulates the constraints of a valid date.

Comment: That does make sense for a setter, that you could abstract it away, plus making your 2 lines into 2 arguments on 1 line.  However, what about using this philosophy on getters?

Comment: Yes, its an example... I'd never not use a datetime  but it's an easy conceptual example...

Comment: If that's what he's arguing and I don't think it is, then it wuold be complete nonsense accessors are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson O-O has behaviour and encapsulated state.  Do you think a class with only property getters/setters is providing behaviour?

Comment: @PeterRitchie. Depends on whether the getter and setter are simply exposing the internal state. There's no difference in terms of the question the OP posed between set {if value != _member { _member = value; DoMemberChanged();}} and SetMember(int value){if value != _member { _member = value; DoMemberChanged();}}. Syntactic sugar...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That's why I mentioned "They decouple implementation from the interface so that what is used as a backing store for the properties can change--but, it rarely ever does; so the properties are simply making available implementation details differently than providing public fields".  Yes, they **can** encapsulate private data, but usually they don't.

Comment: @PeterRitchie It's one of those design compromises we make every day. Most of my forms deal with accessors on a data class, but when there was an obvious advantage I have passed in an Interface implemented by a form to the data class. In a dynamically typed environment that ratio would probably be reversed.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sure, and articles dealing with ideas/suggestions/designs/etc. generally only deal with the concept; they don't deal with how or where it should be applied.  There are certain aspects of an application that are better served by more or exact object-oriented and some that won't.  Data classes or DTOs generally don't have behaviour to start with, so imposing it where it doesn't belong is probably just as evil as that the other was implying in his scenario.  I certainly didn't get "anti-property all the things" out of the article...

Comment: The implication is that where you do have behaviour, providing properties for everything circumvents the behaviour you're trying to provide.  And while is sounds "simple" or "harmless" to provide properties for all your fields, it really isn't--*if your trying to provide behaviour as well*.

Comment: @PeterRitchie. I wouldn't call it harmless either. Making something public when you don't have to is a huge red flag in my book. Don't think we are poles apart here just looking at the issue from different angles. Turned out to be a bit more of a discussion that a question this, but not a worthless one by any means.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are not evil, they just shouldn't be generated automaticaly for every attribute. As far as your example is concerned, a Car class should probably have a getBrand method returning a String, but a setter for this attribute is probably not needed. A method in Car returning a TextBox with the brand name is most probably worse idea than a simple getter returning a String, because it's not very generic.

I can see Peter Ritchie's answer now: good example with the changeDate. The Date class should provide a method like that rather than providing a getter for day and month and requiring user code to compute next day in the calendar on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what he's saying is, say you had a class with ten properties, and you wanted to dump it to a line of csv. Add a Tocsv method to the class to return a string with a pile of csvs in it. Don't write an other class that accesses it through properties and builds the csv string as by necessity they become very tightly coupled.

Not sure why he singled out accessors, the proplem would be exactly they same with discrete methods to get and set, or worse still member variables.

Obviously there are limits, you'd have to have really good reason for replacing

```
SomeLabel.Text = SomeInstance.StringValue;
```

with

```
SomeInstance.MakeStringValueALabel(SomeLabel);
```